# Setting default application for filetypes via CLI?

Tags: debian, libreoffice, mime-types, defaults, file-types

I have 150 Debian Jessie machines that open ODS files in Gnumeric when double-clicked despite LibreOffice Calc being installed. I know it is possible to change this by right-clicking the ODS file and changing its default program from the Properties window, but getting 150 users to do this is not an option. They all use xfce4 and thunar.

I need to do this via CLI so I can do it across all workstations remotely. I have looked in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/application/mimetypes.list` with no luck - comparing the files before and after changing it via GUI revealed no changes here.

How can I use bash to make these workstations open ODS files with LibreOffice Calc by default?

**EDIT**: Unlike the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226857/set-default-pdf-reader), my Jessie installs do not have `~/.config/mimeapps.list` or `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`

Comment: Just as a nit-pick, you're looking for a command-line solution; it doesn't matter that your shell is bash.

Comment: can you check if your systems have the '/usr/share/applications/defaults.list' file? What window managers/file managers are on your systems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set default pdf reader](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226857/set-default-pdf-reader)

Comment: @hyph I don't have a `/usr/share/applications/defaults` or `~/.conf/mimeapps.list`. I'm using xfce and thunar.

Comment: found another existing answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23776/how-to-change-a-file-type-icon-in-xfce-thunar have you seen that one and tried solutions from there?

Comment: @hyph Unfortunately my Jessie installs do not have a `/usr/share/mime` directory either, so that answer is not much help.

Comment: do you have the `update-mime-database` command on your system?

Comment: official documentation seems to be here: https://wiki.debian.org/MimeTypesSupport . Do you have a /usr/lib/mime directory?

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162742/where-does-firefox-get-the-default-applications-for-opening-files-from which also refers to `/etc/mailcap`* and `~/.mailcap`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `mimeopen` with `-d` option:

`man mimeopen` :

```
DESCRIPTION
   This script tries to determine the mimetype of a file and open it with
   the default desktop application. If no default application is
   configured the user is prompted with an "open with" menu in the
   terminal.


-d, --ask-default
       Let the user choose a new default program for given files.
```

Example:

```
mimeopen -d file.mp4
```

sample output:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type video/mp4

   1) VLC media player  (vlc)
   2) Other...
```

Verify it:

```
xdg-open file.mp4
```

Comment: This works! You can also pipe input like so: `echo "2" | mimeopen -d test.ods`

I have just one question: Is there a way to close the window this opens via bash script? If I run this over SSH it cannot open the window on my machine (X11Forwarding is off), so it hangs waiting for it to open. I can ^C out but I'm not sure how to send that input in a script.

Comment: @user5104897 run `ps aux | grep libre` then run `kill PID`

Comment: I can do that manually, but how do I feed the PID to `kill` automatically? For example `ps aux | grep libre | kill` to kill all the PIDs left by the grep, or something like that.

Comment: Only the `PID` witch belongs to Libre Office Calc. Also you can verify the X-forwarding on the remote machine e,g: `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep X11Forwarding`

Comment: Hmm, the last step wont work for me. It runs the program fine, but does not seem to be changing the default application