# strange file association in Firefox when choosing "Open containing folder"

Tags: debian, directory, firefox, desktop-environment, lxde

When I download a file in Firefox and click "Open containing Folder" it opens the folder in Baobab instead of PCMan FM.

I don't know how I ended up with this behaviour; I want Firefox to open it in PCMan FM.

I'm running LXDE on Debian 10.0.

```
$ mimetype ~/Downloads
/home/milo/Downloads: inode/directory

$ grep directory /etc/mime.types 
#  file in their home directory.  Definitions included there will take
application/vnd.japannet-directory-service
application/vnd.noblenet-directory
inode/directory-locked
inode/directory
text/directory

$
```

Comment: I imagine you want it to open in Nautilus?

Comment: actually I want PCMan FM, but yes, it's LXDE equivalent of nautilus. I forgot to include desktop environment in my question

Comment: Firefox has its own [file associations](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-firefox-behavior-when-open-file)

Comment: @FrankSchrijver yes, but there is no association with folders in Firefox settings.

Comment: Ooh, my mistake. What does it say in your /etc/mime.types ? https://wiki.debian.org/MIME/etc/mime.types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18869772/mime-type-for-a-directory

Comment: @FrankSchrijver added info

Comment: Have you read this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350103/setting-default-application-for-filetypes-via-cli ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### mimeopen

```
$ mimeopen Downloads/
Please choose a default application for files of type inode/directory

    1) Disk Usage Analyzer  (org.gnome.baobab)
    2) File Manager PCManFM  (pcmanfm)
    3) Other...

use application #2
Opening "Downloads/" with File Manager PCManFM  (inode/directory)

$ cat .config/mimeapps.list 
[Default Applications]
inode/directory=pcmanfm.desktop;
```

The new config file is created which now defines a default application for folders.

Thanks to [Frank Schrijver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/195347) for pointing me in the right direction.